# Is it possible to write to DynamoDB only when spare capacity is available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an application which receives very predictable, heavy traffic during working hours.  Users typically interact with the app for about 40 minutes at a time.  DynamoDB table A receives a steady stream of writes throughout user sessions and handles things without difficulty.  We attempt to write a large amount of data to table B at the end of each session, however, and early in the day this can result in throttling.  Our tables are billed on-demand (no, this is not something I am able to change), but the sudden spike in writes still causes throttling, [which is expected](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/on-demand-table-throttling-dynamodb/).

The data being written to table A is both critical and time sensitive. The data going to table B is critical and must not be lost, but delays in data availability from table B on the order of a few hours is acceptable, but not ideal. **So I'm looking for a way to say "please write this to the table ASAP, but only as long as it won't cause throttling".** Provisioning for the expected capacity is not an option (don't ask). An SQS queue with a long message delay doesn't really fit the bill because (a) 15 minutes may not be long enough and (b) it doesn't meet the "ASAP" part of the story.  I've considered pre-warming the table, but that's just cludgy.

Comment: why aren't you simply retrying when you get a thottled exception?

Answer (score 1):

So... you take all the expected ways to handle this that were designed and provided by AWS then say you can't use them. That... doesn't leave you much options.

You're pretty much left with designing some custom architecture. Throttling, provisioning, burst provisioning, on demand, and all are all part of the package for handling these kinds of bursts. If you can't use them, then you'll have to do something like write the entry as a json to an s3 bucket and have some cron event pick them up in an hour or something one a time and batch write them to the table.

You may want to take a look at how your table is arranged. If you are having to make a lot of writes all at once (ie, because you have to duplicate data through multiple PK/SK combinations in order to be able to recall it with a single query) then an RDS may be better suited for the task at hand. Dynamo is more for quick and snappy *queries* and not really for extended data logging or storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the secret to DDB on-demand...

From the page you linked to

> For new on-demand tables, you can immediately drive up to 4,000 write
> request units or 12,000 read request units, or any linear combination
> of the two. For an existing table that you switched to on-demand
> capacity mode, the previous peak is half the previous provisioned
> throughput for the table—or the settings for a newly created table
> with on-demand capacity mode, whichever is higher. For more
> information, see Initial throughput for on-demand capacity mode.

And the Inital throughput for on-demand capacity mode page says:

> Initial Throughput for On-Demand Capacity Mode If you recently
> switched an existing table to on-demand capacity mode for the first
> time, or if you created a new table with on-demand capacity mode
> enabled, the table has the following previous peak settings, even
> though the table has not served traffic previously using on-demand
> capacity mode:
>
> Newly created table with on-demand capacity mode: The previous peak is
> 2,000 write request units or 6,000 read request units. You can drive
> up to double the previous peak immediately, which enables newly
> created on-demand tables to serve up to 4,000 write request units or
> 12,000 read request units, or any linear combination of the two.
>
> Existing table switched to on-demand capacity mode: The previous peak
> is half the maximum write capacity units and read capacity units
> provisioned since the table was created, or the settings for a newly
> created table with on-demand capacity mode, whichever is higher. In
> other words, your table will deliver at least as much throughput as it
> did prior to switching to on-demand capacity mode.

The key thing to realize is that DDB on-demand "peaks" are never lowered..

So if you have a table that at some point peaked at 20K WCU, you can scale cleanly from 1-20K without throttling.

In other words, you shouldn't continue to see throttling in an app unless you hit a new peak.

You can also artificially set the peak by changing the table to provisioned at double the expected peak.  Then when you convert it back to on-demand, you'll have a "peak" set for half the provisioned capacity.